# Prevent Google amp-autocomplete from closing/hiding for debugging purpose

Tags: amp-html

I have a following code which works just fine, but I was wondering is it possible to prevent amp-autocomplete component from closing when clicking outside of it. It adds display:none every time when i try to inspect element in crhome, and it would be good to keep it open while developing, so I can inspect CSS with more ease.

```
<i role="button" on="tap:autocomplete" class="header__search" tabindex="0"></i>
<amp-lightbox id="autocomplete" layout="nodisplay" class="autocomplete" on="lightboxOpen:autocomplete-query-input.focus">
    <form class="sample-form"
          method="post"
          action-xhr="https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/api/echo"
          target="_top">

        <amp-autocomplete filter="none" class="autocomplete__component" src="/api/amp/autocomplete" query="query" min-characters="2">
            <i class="autocomplete__back" on="tap:quote-lb.close" tabindex="-1" role="button"></i>
            <input id="autocomplete-query-input" name="query" class="autocomplete__input">
            <template type="amp-mustache" class="autocomplete__result">
                <div data-value="{{Label}}" class="autocomplete__result-item">
                    <a href="/{{Url}}" >
                        <amp-img layout="fixed" width="27" height="21" src="@GlobalVars.ImageCdnHost{{Image}}?w=27&h=21"></amp-img>
                        <span>{{Label}}</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </template>

        </amp-autocomplete>
    </form>
</amp-lightbox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if just find in dev-tools results container, i.e.:

```
<div class="i-amphtml-autocomplete-results" role="listbox" id="72_AMP_content_" hidden="">
```

and delete hidden="" ? Of course, not an ideal solution, but you get this in chrome to scratch css.

All the best,
V.

Comment: I do that now, but every time I refresh a page, I need to re-do it again. It's not friendly for work.

Comment: Hi Robert, looks like this is the only one solution in this case, because AMP autocomplete results container initially empty and it's src data is being fetched/triggered on user interation only. If you need static html you can copy the result into external .html file and do your work with css there.